# MySQL : Count returning double the number of entries when using distinct

Tags: mysql

So I do a count like so

```
select distinct count(prod.id) from product as prod....
```

I get back 175590

I do a select like so

```
select distinct prod.id from product as prod.... (rest of the query is exactly the same)
```

and I limit it. Now if I limit the query to return anything over the half way point it returns nothing. It appears as if count is returning double the number of entries each time.

Does anyone know of anything that may be causing this?

Thanks
Tracey

Comment: `distinct count(prod.id)` does not do anything it will return just the count, perhaps you are looking at `count(distinct prod.id)`

Comment: That is exactly the problem. Duh. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` keyword tells `MySQL` to strip the duplicate rows from the result set. Because `SELECT COUNT(prod.id)` returns a single row (I guess this, I cannot tell for sure until I see the complete query), adding `DISTINCT` in front of `COUNT()` does not change its behaviour in any way.

What you probably want is `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prod.id)` and that's a totally different thing. It removes the duplicate values of `prod.id` before counting them.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is counting how many prod.id's there are.
Your second query is showing all distinct prod.id's.

This is quite different.

If you were to do the second query without the distinct key word the number would be the same.